# How do I substract each element in a list with each other on python

Tags: list

I'm very new to coding so I need help with a list substraction.
I will run an experiment 50 times and each time I'll get data (numbers). The q1, q2,... etc represent the numbers I'll add to the list after I run the experiment.

I will need to substract each element from all of the others.
Example:

```
myList = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, ...]
```

Then, I'll have to code using a for loop (probably, I'm not sure), for the program to get each element and substract with each other:

```
q5-q4, q5-q3, q5-q2, q5-q1

q4-q3, q4-q2, q4-q1

q3-q2,q3-q1

q2-q1
```

something like that. It could be fast if I didn't have to take 50 data points, so I'm not sure how I'm going to loop on that.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for your example but please double check and let me know as well. Seeing your example I see that you start from the last element and so:

```
    m = [21, 45, 35, 44, 56]
    m = list(reversed(m))
    final = []
    
    for i, num in enumerate(m):
        if i < len(m) - 1:
            temp = [x[0]-x[1] for x in zip([num]*(len(m)-(i+1)),m[i+1:])]
            final.append(temp)
    
    print(final)
```

The output is:

```
>> [[12, 21, 11, 35], [9, -1, 23], [-10, 14], [24]]
```

1. Used reversed to get the last element to be the first one
2. Enumerate gives me the list element and its index
3. I don't want to subtract the last element with itself hence the if condition
4. temp is a list of the current element being subtracted by each of its smaller indexed elements (of the original unreversed list)
5. [num]*(len(m)-(i+1)) gives me a list of the same element with length of the list as much as the remaining list. For example for 56, this list looks like [56, 56, 56, 56].
6. This is then subtracted by each corresponding element of the list and is achieved by zip.

Note: If you don't want a list of lists, you can used extend instead of append and it will give you one big list as seen below:

```
>> [12, 21, 11, 35, 9, -1, 23, -10, 14, 24]
```

PS: A more pythonic way we can achieve this is using an anonymous (lambda function) and map as below:

```
m = [21, 45, 35, 44, 56]
m = list(reversed(m))
length = len(m)
final = []

for i, num in enumerate(m):
    if i < len(m) - 1:
        final.extend(map(lambda x, y: x-y, [num]*(length-(i+1)), m[i+1:]))
```

What the function does?

1. map(function, iterable1, iterable2) takes a function which in this case is an anonymous function called lambda and passes two arguments to it x and y. x is from iterable1 and y is from iterable2.
2. (lambda arg1, arg2: arg1-arg2) is the function given as input to map which takes x from list 1 and y from list 2 and subtracts each element to give use a consolidated value.
3. All extend does is takes this output map object and extends the already existing list with it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! And all the explanations are 100%! Thank you!